# Chaosmonkey can't communicate with Spinnaker

Tags: openssl, spinnaker, chaos

I'm trying to run chaosmonkey and getting following error when I try to connect spinnaker using the command `chaosmonkey config {app-name}`.

```
http get failed at https://api.spinnaker.{company}.com:085/applications/chaosdemo?expand=false
github.com/Netflix/chaosmonkey/spinnaker.Spinnaker.Get
    /go/src/github.com/Netflix/chaosmonkey/spinnaker/config.go:32
github.com/Netflix/chaosmonkey/spinnaker.(*Spinnaker).Get
    <autogenerated>:1
github.com/Netflix/chaosmonkey/command.DumpConfig
    /go/src/github.com/Netflix/chaosmonkey/command/dumpconfig.go:27
github.com/Netflix/chaosmonkey/command.Execute
    /go/src/github.com/Netflix/chaosmonkey/command/chaosmonkey.go:327
main.main
    /go/src/github.com/netflix/chaosmonkey/cmd/chaosmonkey/main.go:35
runtime.main
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:198
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2361#
```

I used .p12 file and its password (used for p12 certificate). The password is not encrypted. Does chaosmonkey expect that password in an encrypted format even though I haven't updated default `decryptor` in `chaosmonkey.toml`

chaosmonkey.toml looks like below

```
[chaosmonkey]
enabled = true
schedule_enabled = true
leashed = true
accounts = ["qa-k8s-cluster"]
time_zone = "America/New_York"

[database]
host = "host"
name = "chaosmonkey"
user = "chaosmonkey"
encrypted_password = "password not encrypted"

[spinnaker]
endpoint = "https://api.spinnaker.{company}.com:085"
certificate = "/apps/chaosmonkey/client.p12"        # path to p12 file when using client-side tls certs
encrypted_password = "password - not encrypted" # password used for p12 certificate, encrypted by decryptor
user = "root" # user associated with terminations, sent in API call to terminate
```

Any help on solving this issue would be appreciated

NOTE

I don't think its something related to .p12 file and its passord because I validated the .p12 to file using `openssl pkcs12 -info -in {file.p12}`

UPDATE

I got it working using .pem file and .key instead of .p12 and its password.

Comment: @d0bry - both Spinnaker and chaos monkey are deployed in kube clusters so that's why kubernetes label was added but I could be more specific about that.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the user the solution was to use the SSH format **.pem** and **.key** file instead of **.p12** format.

For more details on Integrating Chaos Monkey with Spinnaker Please refer to the Medium.com and OPSMX.com resources at:

[running-chaos-monkey-on-spinnaker](https://blog.spinnaker.io/running-chaos-monkey-on-spinnaker-google-compute-engine-gce-155dc52f20ef)
[Integrating Chaos Monkey with Spinnaker](https://blog.opsmx.com/integrating-chaos-monkey-with-spinnaker/)